# Setting session cookie on root domain and one specific subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, session-cookies

In my Rails app, I'm building out a new frontend with Vue and adding some API controllers. To authenticate on the Vue side, I'd like to continue using the existing Devise login pages which will exist on the site's root domain, `mydomain.com`. The Vue app will live on `app.mydomain.com`.

Is it possible to share the Devise session cookie between the root domain and `app.mydomain.com`, but not any other subdomains? I don't want the session cookie shared to `staging.mydomain.com` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `config/initializers/session_store.rb` and put there

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  key: '_your_app_session',
  domain: %w(mydomain.com app.mydomain.com)
}
```